# After getting a new router computers wont detect each other on the network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Details: All computers on Windows 7 or 8. The computers don't pop up in the network folder except when on wired. I also can't connect with Xbox Smart Glass any of our devices to our Xbox and I cannot use my tv's remote app and all share with any of our devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have client isolation (sometimes called "AP isolation") enabled in the router. This prevents wireless devices from talking to each other. If you give us the router's make and model, we can tell you exactly where to find this in the configuration.

Comment: It is a Netgear N600 WNDR3700

Comment: `Advanced` -> `Wireless Settings` -> `Enable Wireless Isolation` (Make sure it's unchcked. Check both bands.)